# Button click that stays active for all users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Looking for some help with a problem i am facing, I am working on a project where  we have a page that contains buttons with statuses, for example full, empty, half-full etc, These are designed to show that status of trucks as they pass through several systems, as they do, 1 of many people can select a button and it should update on all screens.

So something like this.

Truck enters stage one, user clicks button on stage one section of the page and that is then displayed to everyone who views the site on the internet.

I have no code at the moment as it is still be planned out.

I am stumped on the best way to achieve this, so any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help you debug existing code, not to write new code for you. Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself and feel free to come back if you're having specific problems.

Comment: Could you please give us the basis for your code at least?

Comment: The best I could think is that you have three buttons for different options.

Comment: /agree with @Blazemonger here. You should put some work into your issue, or perhaps hire a contractor.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Alternately, use WebSockets, which solves the issue I describe below by allowing server and client to interact two-ways. [Have a link!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

---

Think of a web application in terms of server and client. The server cannot send requests; only the client can send requests to the server, which can respond to these requests.

In your application, the server should at all times keep track of the state of all buttons (e.g. whether they are pressed or not). Whenever a client presses a button, it sends a request to the server, which now knows to change the state.

The problem now is sending this new state to all of the other clients. Since the server can only respond to requests, not initiate them, that means all of our other clients must be waiting on a response from the server at all times.

Thus, the solution is to have each client constantly have an unanswered request to the server. Whenever the server responds, immediately send back another request (anticipating the next state change).

Tangentially: this is how many real-time chat applications work, including Facebook chat. If you open the developer tools on your console, you can actually see your browser sending and waiting on requests.

Comment: @mpf82 `WebSockets` would be the nicer way, but how is support for it? I have slept for many years...

Comment: It's supported by mostly all major browsers - http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets